# Is there a simple way to move Google Chrome bookmark information into a Word document?

Tags: google-chrome

I need to move the information (such as links, titles, structure) of my Google Chrome bookmarks into a Word document (or a text file) for work. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You can only export chrome's bookmark to a html file, but you can parse it afterward to keep only the informations you need... See : https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The best you can do is export Chrome Bookmarks as HTML file.
2. Open the saved HTML file with Chrome again.
3. Copy everything.
4. Create a new Word document and paste everything with formatting.